# Meteor: How to override verify email popup dialog which appears after clicking email verification link

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I want to add some fields to popup dialog which appears when user click on verification email link sent to there email. Actually i want to extend the sign up process. So when user clicked on verify link i want to show some more fields like zip code and date of birth in popup and on clicking save those fields should save to user modal.
Any help will be highly appreciated. I am new to meteor.

I am using [ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3](https://atmospherejs.com/ian/accounts-ui-bootstrap-3) for sign up process.

Answer (score 1):

Some more details if needed !

With the following package, you can replace templates :

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension

So you create your own template, then replace the default one :

```
Template.emailVerifiedDialog.replaces("_justVerifiedEmailDialog")
```

Your dialog will be shown on every pages, you have to add the behaviour to make it visible when necessary

```
Template.emailVerifiedDialog.helpers({
  visible: function () {
    return loginButtonsSession.get('justVerifiedEmail');
 }
```

And manage click button event :

```
Template.emailVerifiedDialog.events({
 'click #just-verified-dismiss-button': function () {
   loginButtonsSession.set('justVerifiedEmail', false);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found solution myself.

Here it is if some one else also looking for this.
We can override email popup dialog by overriding **login_buttons_dialogs.html** file in **/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3** folder.